# Render a Graph (Chart) "silent" in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, graph, rendering

I have a program that checks in a file every X minutes and render a graph (sorry, a chart) by the data in this file.

Is there a way to build this program to run in the background, and instead of showing the graph, it export this graph as an image to a specified folder? That is, i wanna render the graph without displaying it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this WinForms, ASP.Net, WPF? What are you using to create the chart? Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: Yea, it's a winform. And i actually found the solution; .SaveImage(). too stupid and simple....

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt find the soultion on google, but i found it scrolling down the suggestion list for my chart. The function is called .SaveFile(), where i type the address. Too simple